# webpack-dev-server didn't refresh the page

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

I'm a noob trying to use webpack-dev-server for development on this multi-entries webpack v5 project. All of the compiled output are under the folder of "dist".
Here is my setting in webpack.config.

```js
const config = {
  mode: 'development',

  target: 'web',

  entry: batch.entry,

  output: {
    publicPath: '/dist/', 
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name]/[name].js',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/i,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource', 
        generator: {
          filename: 'static/[hash][ext][query]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: true, 
    port: 5004, 
    liveReload: true    
    watchFiles: ['dist/**/*'],
    devMiddleware: {
      publicPath: '/dist/',
    },
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      watch: true,
    },
    open: ['./dist/html/layout/layout.htm'],
  },

  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single', 
  },
};

module.exports = () => {
  return config;
};
```

And here are the issues that I encountered...

1. When I set the configs just like above, the page didn't get refreshed, so the page conducted the old code then the new code.
2. After updating the publicPath of output, the refresh fn works as it should.

```js
output: {
    -publicPath: '/dist', 
    +publicPath: '/dist/', 
  },
```

However right now the paths of my svg and ttf just get concatenated without "/" and all of fontawesome icons do not show.

```
GET http://localhost:5004/diststatic/491974d108fe4002b2aa.ttf
GET http://localhost:5004/diststatic/8751ddd8d424faecfa6f.svg
```

And at the same time the image is still on the right path.

```
<img style="width: 400px;object-fit: contain;" src="/dist/static/0bde0707c00b6b3ef5f6.jpg" alt="">
```

I've tried to make the filename of this category starting with "./" but then the path became `http://localhost:5004/dist/./static/491974d108fe4002b2aa.ttf` so this is another dead end.

```js
{
  test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
  type: 'asset/resource', 
  generator: {
    -filename: 'static/[hash][ext][query]',
    +filename: './static/[hash][ext][query]',
    },
},
```

Because I've not seen any posts of talking about the same issue, so maybe I neglect and misunderstand some of the essential setting for this?
Let me know if anymore information is needed to clarify the situation. Thanks.

Comment: Place slash at the end of the folder in: `directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/')`

Comment: Tried this one too but no luck. The slash was ignored somehow.
Also different ways such as
1. adding the slash in output: { publicPath: '/dist/', } => no refresh on the page, but the path was ok to load .ttf and .svg

Comment: Ok, so now you have correct `path` to your static files. The another problem is `page refresh` Do you mean `hot reload`? Simply when you change some files, webpack will rebuild static file?

Comment: Yes, hot reload it is. So with  the slash in output: { publicPath: '/dist/', } => if I change from `console.log("test")` to `console.log("test2")`, then `test` AND `test2` are both shown. But after refreshing the page by my own, there will be only `test2`.

Comment: From what you wrote, hot reload means, that webpack will rebuild and generate files for you without need to do it manually from console. But it doesn't refresh the web page. You have to do it by yourself. Ctrl+Shift+R should also clear the browser cache and should see only `test2` in console.